# delete rows between tables with identical tr id

Tags: javascript

I have two tables and with same tr ids and content (for some reason)!

When I click a check a box in table1 I should be able to delete that row in both table1 and table2 etc. How can I achieve this?
I can delete from table1 using

```
table1.on('click','tr .lowBox:checked',function(){

    $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 

}
```

How do I delete row from table2.

thanks!

Comment: Are you also using jQuery within your page?

Comment: you shouldn't have two elements with same id, it will only ever point to the first id found. see https://jsfiddle.net/v2mk69ss/

Comment: Can you post your html as part of this question?

Answer (score 0):

```js
table1.on('click','tr .lowBox:checked',function(){

  $(this).closest('tr').remove(); //send to var to perform as below
  $("table2").closest('tr').remove(); //If you're traversing UP
  $("table2").find('tr').remove(); //If you're traversing DOWN
  //Inside your "click" event, you can traverse any part of the DOM
  //regardless of where you entered the document with your click event
  //slightly more robust, you could do this..
  /*or as fed variables...e
  var $item1 = $(this).closest('tr');
  var $item2 = $("table2").closest('tr');
  var $rmTwo = function(item1,item2){
    $(item1).remove();
    $(item2).remove();
  }
  //Then execute your repeatable function, using the two tr's
  $rmTwo($item1,$item2); 
  // should remove both, and you can play
  //with your jQuery to get the correct elements
  //or alter them if you change your code structure.
}
```

This would be the closest I can get you without seeing any of your HTML, and under the assumption that you're using jQuery on your page.

Comment: I don't think this will do what the question described, because the `table2` isn't a child of a "tr" (also that'd be `"#table2"` not `"table2"`. What the the OP is trying to do is delete the same row on the other table.

Comment: Nope, none of above is working. My test case is here: https://jsfiddle.net/7v1mcaL7/

Comment: I am sure I am doing some thing silly. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Slightly different version utilizing row.remove() is here :https://jsfiddle.net/7v1mcaL7/2/

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, you shouldn't have duplicate IDs. Instead you could use classes, or generate IDs that are unique (for example, by prefixing with the table id). However, if you must do it this way, here's what you could do:

```js
table1.on('click','tr .lowBox:checked',function(){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    table2.children("#" + row[0].id).remove();
    row.remove();
}
```

If you switch to table-unique classes for each row:

```js
table1.on('click','tr .lowBox:checked',function(){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    table2.children("." + row[0].className).remove();
    row.remove();
}
```

This solution makes a few assumptions about the structure of your HTML. I can update it if you post a more detailed sample of your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with:

```
    table1DT=var $('#table1').dataTable({});
    table2DT=var $('#table2').dataTable({});

    table1DT.on('click','tr .lowBox:checked',function(){
    var row= $(this).closest('tr');    

    //do some thing with row variable

    var d=row.attr('id');
    var nRow =  $('#table2 tbody tr[id='+d+']')[0];

    table2DT.fnDeleteRow(nRow);
    table1DT.fnDeleteRow(row);
}
```

so checking the table1 check box would delete that particular row in table1 and table2 etc.